# Unused arguments at function R

Tags: r

I'm new in R.

Trying to use the rtriangle function.

```
swimmerToTornado <- trajectory("to tornado")%>%
  log_("Going down TORNADO") %>%
  addService(sname = "Tornado", timeDist = function() rtriangle( min = 0.1, max = 0.5, mode = 0.5) )
```

But I get this Error -

```
Error in rtriangle(1, min = 0.1, max = 0.5, mode = 0.5) : 
  unused arguments (min = 0.1, max = 0.5, mode = 0.5)
```

I tried to remove the 1 argument - still the same error.

Comment: If you are using this function https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/triangle/versions/0.12/topics/triangle , then the names of the arguments are `a=`, `b=` and `c=` (not `min=`, `max=` and `mode=`)

Comment: thanks! should put it as an answer so I could approve it  @jogo

Comment: it is only a typo that caused the error. (solvable by reading the documentation of the function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
swimmerToTornado <- trajectory("to tornado")%>%
  log_("Going down TORNADO") %>%
  addService(sname = "Tornado", timeDist = function() rtriangle( 1,0.1, 0.5, 0.5))
```

Or just like the comment above by @jogo, doing `a=` , `b=`, `c=` will work too.